# What is the name for this auth pattern used by PyPI with tokens?

Tags: authentication, token, pypi

If you use PyPI for uploading files, you can authenticate using a username and password, or you can authenticate using just a token, and sending the string `__token__`, and then the token with a prefix:

> To use an API token:
>
> ```
> Set your username to __token__
> Set your password to the token value, including the pypi- prefix
> ```

You can see more details on their page here:
https://pypi.org/help/#apitoken

This seems quite clever - it doesn't break the experience for people using old style credentials, but allows you to tie a reduced set of privileges to a given token, which seems safer.

What is the name of this pattern, where both ways of authing are supported like this? I mean beyond the name 'token based authentication', as that doesn't account for the fallback offered here.

And beyond the obvious downside that only needs to get their hands on the token to send possibly malicious requests, what are the other downsides to this approach?

I'm working with RSS in a project, and it seems a nice way to provide access to legacy RSS readers, while still supporting more use cases of an API.

Comment: I think your title and tags are off: you meant PyPI not PyPy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyPI admin here: we call that a "compromise" . PyPI needs to be entirely backwards-compatible with existing clients that only support basic HTTP auth, so this was really the only option available to us with that constraint.

I'm not sure there's a better name for it. There are some other examples of this in use in varying ways:

- https://api.data.gov/docs/api-key/ (API key as username, empty password)
- https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication (API key as username, empty password)
- https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#via-oauth-and-personal-access-tokens (Regular username, API key as password)

Comment: Ah, thanks for this extra context Dustin!

Answer (score 0):

After tad more digging through the [issues on the warehouse project on github](https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/994) it turns out that the passwords/password approach with the `pypy-` prefix are actually much more powerful than I first thought.

Based on a kind of auth credential called a Maracoon, [as described in this paper from google](https://research.google/pubs/pub41892/)

> This paper introduces macaroons: flexible authorization credentials for Cloud services that support decentralized delegation between principals. Macaroons are based on a construction that uses nested, chained MACs (e.g., HMACs) in a manner that is highly efficient, easy to deploy, and widely applicable.
>
> Although macaroons are bearer credentials, like Web cookies, macaroons embed caveats that attenuate and contextually confine when, where, by who, and for what purpose a target service should authorize requests. This paper describes macaroons and motivates their design, compares them to other credential systems, such as cookies and SPKI/SDSI, evaluates and measures a prototype implementation, and discusses practical security and application considerations. In particular, it is considered how macaroons can enable more fine-grained authorization in the Cloud, e.g., by strengthening mechanisms like OAuth2, and a formalization of macaroons is given in authorization logic.

There's a [video introducing the idea - Macaroons: Cookies with Contextual Caveats for Decentralized Authorization in the Cloud,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGBZO5n_SUg)

After a quick look around I've found libraries written in [python](https://github.com/ecordell/pymacaroons) and [go](https://github.com/go-macaroon/macaroon), and [c](https://github.com/rescrv/libmacaroons).